# Better way to parameterize Salesforce reports

Tags: reporting, visualforce-component, filters

- I have created a new Salesforce report, added AccountID in the filter and left it blank.
- Then while generating the report url I append pv0 at the end with AccountID

> https://mydomain.salesforce.com/[Report_Id]?pv0=[AccountID]

This looks like a hacky way. Is there a better way to generate parameterized reports?

Answer (score 1):

You can use few filters

```
pv0 = Account Id
pv1 = AccountType
pv2 = Custom field
```

This way you can construct url

```
/ReportId?pv0={!Account.Id}&pv1={!Account.Type}&pv2={!Account.Key_Account__c}
```

You can add like this.

**Source:** [salesforce-reports-url-hack](http://www.salesforceben.com/)

---

### Updates

```
/00O18000000Ldis?
ptable0=0721800000021Nf
&ocond0=w
&rtable0=CampaignMember-Campaign
&rtablecol0=Contact
&sfpc0_0=Name
&sfpn0_0=eq
&sfpv0_0={!Campaign.Name}
```

> Notice the ptable0 is not a literal text such as ACCOUNT_ID, it's an
>   Id. You can find it easily in chrome (right click on the filter and
>   click inspect element) if you apply the cross filter to explore what
>   values you need. You'll have to scroll up a bit until you see a bunch
>   of

[image]

> Just remember to remove the cross filter when you save the report.

**Source** [Dynamic Report using Cross Filters](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D3KuAAK)

Comment: in addition to this excellent answer, if any of the `pvX` parameters are special date filters, you have to use the SOQL versions -- e.g. `THIS_QUARTER` as `THIS QUARTER` will not work

Answer (score 1):

Below is a screenshot of a report criteria. There are three fields in the criteria that you will need to pass data to in order to  fully control the criteria.
[image]

pc0: Corresponds to the field in the report criteria.

pn0: Corresponds to the operator in the report criteria.

pv0: Corresponds to the value in the report criteria.

These inputs are 0 based that means that you will access the first set of filter fields using 0 (e.g. pc0, pn0, pv0). As you add more filters, you just increase the number (pc0, pc1, pc2...).

Now to the operators. Here are the values that Salesforce is expecting:

> eq = equals ne = not equals lt = less than le = less than or equals gt
>   = greater than ge = greater than or equals co = contains nc = does not contain sw = starts with in = includes

You can then append filter parameters at your leisure.

```
"/00OU0000000aYlZ?pc0=ACCOUNT_ID&pn0=eq&pv0={!Account.Id}&pc1=WON&pn1=eq&pv1=TRUE
```

For details click: [hacking-cross-filter-reports](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/06/03/url-hacking-cross-filter-reports/)