# Question from sales guy: library lookup within an Opportunity

Tags: reporting, lookup, libraries

Preface: I'm not a developer, but looking for help. My sales org uses Lightning version -- within the Opportunity, I would like the opportunity to lookup in our Library the Close Won / Close Lost reasons for other Opportunities that had the same Product or Line Description.

Creating a Report that can Filter by those Product/Line Description fields won't work as we have over 26k SKUs (configurable products). I am hoping for a solution that accesses the specific Product/Line Description within the individual Opportunity to cross-reference only those other Opportunities with the same Product/Line Description, and could then filter by Won / Lost. Open to Salesforce specific solutions, or external solutions that would access the Salesforce libraries and create the view.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to parameterize Salesforce reports](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110219/better-way-to-parameterize-salesforce-reports)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to clarify what you mean by libraries.  Do you mean  Content Libraries where files are stored?  How are these related to Opportunity Products / opportunity line items in your organization?